# puma gem and ssl errors while doing bundle install

Tags: ruby, openssl, rubygems, rvm

I am running bundle install to gems but it is failing for some gems.
Currently, it's breaking for puma gem (An error occurred while installing puma (3.6.0), and Bundler cannot continue).
these are the logs for the same

```
To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/pusingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@pm/extensions/x86_64-darwin-19/2.3.0/puma-3.6.0/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/pusingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@pm/gems/puma-3.6.0/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/pusingh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.7@pm/gems/puma-3.6.0/ext/puma_http11
make "DESTDIR="
compiling http11_parser.c
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.rl:111:17: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'long' and 'unsigned long'
[-Wsign-compare]
  assert(pe - p == len - off && "pointers aren't same distance");
         ~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/assert.h:93:25: note: expanded from macro 'assert'
    (__builtin_expect(!(e), 0) ? __assert_rtn(__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, #e) : (void)0)
                        ^
ext/puma_http11/http11_parser.c:43:18: warning: unused variable 'puma_parser_en_main' [-Wunused-const-variable]
static const int puma_parser_en_main = 1;
                 ^
2 warnings generated.
compiling io_buffer.c
compiling mini_ssl.c
mini_ssl.c:90:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct dh_st'
  dh->p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof(dh1024_p), NULL);
  ~~^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:104:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct dh_st'
typedef struct dh_st DH;
               ^
mini_ssl.c:91:5: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct dh_st'
  dh->g = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_g, sizeof(dh1024_g), NULL);
  ~~^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:104:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct dh_st'
typedef struct dh_st DH;
               ^
mini_ssl.c:93:10: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct dh_st'
  if ((dh->p == NULL) || (dh->g == NULL)) {
       ~~^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:104:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct dh_st'
typedef struct dh_st DH;
               ^
mini_ssl.c:93:29: error: incomplete definition of type 'struct dh_st'
  if ((dh->p == NULL) || (dh->g == NULL)) {
                          ~~^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:104:16: note: forward declaration of 'struct dh_st'
typedef struct dh_st DH;
               ^
mini_ssl.c:197:27: warning: 'DTLSv1_method' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  conn->ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_method());
                          ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h:1895:1: note: 'DTLSv1_method' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *DTLSv1_method(void)) /* DTLSv1.0 */
^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:155:34: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0'
# define DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(f)   DECLARE_DEPRECATED(f)
                                 ^
/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:118:55: note: expanded from macro 'DECLARE_DEPRECATED'
#   define DECLARE_DEPRECATED(f)    f __attribute__ ((deprecated));
                                                      ^
mini_ssl.c:233:20: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  int verify_err = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
      ~~~~~~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
mini_ssl.c:246:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
      err = ERR_get_error();
          ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
3 warnings and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

> I am using ruby 2.3.7 with catalina mac os 10.15.5 Please help

Comment: Try a newer ruby.