# Unable to install puma on macOS 12 due to SSL error

Tags: ruby, openssl, rvm, puma

I am running into the following error when trying to bundle install the puma gem. Ruby is installed with rvm (1.29.12-next). I believe the issue has something to do with openSSL, but i have no idea how exactly. I have openSSL installed via homebrew.

- Ruby 3.0.6
- macOS: 12.6.1

The only other similar question i've found [was this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291722/puma-gem-and-ssl-errors-while-doing-bundle-install) but the only suggestion there is to try a newer version of Ruby; this isn't an option for me as I specifically need 3.0.6 to be compatible on Heroku's heroku-20 platform

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   [0/383]
                                                                               
current directory: /Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6/gems/puma-6.3.0/ext/puma_http11                                                                       
/Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/bin/ruby -I /Users/tony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.6/lib/ruby/3.0.0 -r ./siteconf20230713-8369-4of5qc.rb extconf.rb              
checking for BIO_read() in -llibcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new() in -lssl... yes
checking for openssl/bio.h... yes 
checking for DTLS_method() in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(NULL, 0) in openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for TLS_server_method() in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(NULL, 0) in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for X509_STORE_up_ref()... no
checking for SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(NULL, 0) in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for SSL_CTX_set_dh_auto(NULL, 0) in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for SSL_get1_peer_certificate() in openssl/ssl.h... no
checking for Random.bytes... yes
creating Makefile            
                                                                               
current directory: /Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6/gems/puma-6.3.0/ext/puma_http11                                                                           
make DESTDIR\= clean    
                                                                               
current directory: /Users/tony/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.6/gems/puma-6.3.0/ext/puma_http11                                                                           
make DESTDIR\=                 
compiling http11_parser.c       
compiling mini_ssl.c      
mini_ssl.c:329:32: error: implicit declaration of function 'SSL_CTX_get0_param' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]                   
    X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = SSL_CTX_get0_param(ctx);
                               ^
mini_ssl.c:329:32: note: did you mean 'SSL_CTX_set1_param'?
/Users/tony/.rvm/usr//include/openssl/ssl.h:1824:5: note: 'SSL_CTX_set1_param' declared here                                                                  
int SSL_CTX_set1_param(SSL_CTX *ctx, X509_VERIFY_PARAM *vpm);
    ^                           
mini_ssl.c:329:24: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion initializing 'X509_VERIFY_PARAM *' (aka 'struct X509_VERIFY_PARAM_st *') with an expression of type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]                                                                                                                         
    X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param = SSL_CTX_get0_param(ctx);
                       ^       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning and 1 error generated.    
make: *** [mini_ssl.o] Error 1                                    

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: I would: uninstall OpenSSL and Ruby. Then re-install openssl@1.1 and then re-install Ruby with `rvm install 3.0.6 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)`

Comment: @spickermann BLESS YOU SIR, that seems to have done it! Feel free to leave an answer and i'll accept. Literally never would have figured that one out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ruby 3.1 was the first version supporting OpenSSL 3 and there are [no plans to back port OpenSSL 3 support to Ruby <=3.0.x](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18658#note-18). When you want to install a Ruby version prior to 3.1 (like 3.0.6 in your case) then you have to use OpenSSL 1.1.

To fix your setup, I suggest the following steps:

1. Uninstall all versions of OpenSSL
2. Uninstall Ruby
3. Reinstall OpenSSL@1.1 with

   ```
   brew install openssl@1.1
   ```
4. Reinstall Ruby 3.0.6 with linking to OpenSSL 1.1 with:

   ```
   rvm install 3.0.6 --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)
   ```